# Center caption but ignore certain parts of TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, captions

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage[list]{subcaption}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, fit, positioning, calc, shapes.arrows}

\usepackage[active, tightpage, floats, displaymath]{preview}

\mathtoolsset{%
  mathic=true
}

% Vectors and matrices
\renewcommand*{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\trans}{\intercal}

% Operators
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{margin={2.5cm, 0cm}}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.60\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
      \node[draw, rectangle, label=below:the] (the) {\(\mat W\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, right=of the, label=below:cat] (cat) {\(\mat W\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, right=of cat, label=below:sat] (sat) {\(\mat W\)};

      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(the.west) (the.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of the] (in_the) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(cat.west) (cat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of cat] (in_cat) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(sat.west) (sat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of sat] (in_sat) {};

      \node[draw, rectangle, fit={($(cat.west) + (-8pt,0pt)$) ($(cat.east) + (8pt,0pt)$)}, pattern=vertical lines, above=2cm of cat] (in) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, above=of in, label=above:mat] (out) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};

      \node[left=of the, outer sep=0] (embed) {embed};
      \node[above=2cm of embed, outer sep=0] (concatenate) {concatenate};
      \node[above=1cm of concatenate, outer sep=0] {softmax};

      \foreach \word in {the, cat, sat}{%
        \draw[->] (\word) -- (in_\word);
        \draw[->] (in_\word) -- (in);
      }

      \draw[->] (in) -- (out);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{CBOW model}\label{fig:cbow}
  \end{subfigure}
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{margin={0cm,0cm}}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
      \node[draw, rectangle, label=below:cat] (cat) {\(\mat W\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(cat.west) (cat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of cat] (in) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, above=2cmof in, label=above:on] (on) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, left=of on, label=above:sat] (sat) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, right=of on, label=above:the] (the) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};

      \draw[->] (cat) -- (in);
      \foreach \word in {sat, on, the}{%
        \draw[->] (in) -- (\word);
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Skip\=/gram model}\label{fig:sg}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{\protect\Verb+Word2Vec+ with vocabulary size \(V\), context
    size \(C\), and embedding size \(N\)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Which typesets into:

[image: Word2Vec Illustration]

As you can see, I have "centered" the "(a) CBOW model" caption by using `\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin={2.5cm, 0cm}}`.  My question is: is it possible not to have to do this?  Or at least somehow calculate the correct width by which I need to offset the caption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\useasboundingbox` in TikZ to set the dimension of the picture. TikZ will then ignore everything after that command for calculating the picture size. With `(current bounding box)` you can reference the size of the picture so far. As long as you draw everything, which should count for the paper size, before the line `\useasboundingbox (current bounding box)` the picture will have the desired size.

Additionally, an empty `subfigure` is needed to allow for the overlap to the left. So it has to be the first. Of course the width of the left (well, now middle) subfigure has to be adjusted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage[list]{subcaption}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, fit, positioning, calc, shapes.arrows}

\usepackage[active, tightpage, floats, displaymath]{preview}

\mathtoolsset{%
  mathic=true
}

% Vectors and matrices
\renewcommand*{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\trans}{\intercal}

% Operators
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
% no longer needed
%  \captionsetup[subfigure]{margin={2.5cm, 0cm}}
  %empty subfugure to allow for overlap to the left
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
  \mbox{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.40\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
      \node[draw, rectangle, label=below:the] (the) {\(\mat W\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, right=of the, label=below:cat] (cat) {\(\mat W\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, right=of cat, label=below:sat] (sat) {\(\mat W\)};

      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(the.west) (the.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of the] (in_the) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(cat.west) (cat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of cat] (in_cat) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(sat.west) (sat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of sat] (in_sat) {};

      \node[draw, rectangle, fit={($(cat.west) + (-8pt,0pt)$) ($(cat.east) + (8pt,0pt)$)}, pattern=vertical lines, above=2cm of cat] (in) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, above=of in, label=above:mat] (out) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};

      % set the picture size to everything drawn so far
      \useasboundingbox (current bounding box);

      % not taken into account for the picture size
      \node[left=of the, outer sep=0] (embed) {embed};
      \node[above=2cm of embed, outer sep=0] (concatenate) {concatenate};
      \node[above=1cm of concatenate, outer sep=0] {softmax};

      % this belongs to the main part, but it doesn't increase its size
      % otherwise it must be moved before \useasboundingbox
      \foreach \word in {the, cat, sat}{%
        \draw[->] (\word) -- (in_\word);
        \draw[->] (in_\word) -- (in);
      }

      \draw[->] (in) -- (out);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{CBOW model}\label{fig:cbow}
  \end{subfigure}
% no longer needed
%  \captionsetup[subfigure]{margin={0cm,0cm}}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
      \node[draw, rectangle, label=below:cat] (cat) {\(\mat W\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(cat.west) (cat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of cat] (in) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, above=2cmof in, label=above:on] (on) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, left=of on, label=above:sat] (sat) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, right=of on, label=above:the] (the) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};

      \draw[->] (cat) -- (in);
      \foreach \word in {sat, on, the}{%
        \draw[->] (in) -- (\word);
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Skip\=/gram model}\label{fig:sg}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{\protect\Verb+Word2Vec+ with vocabulary size \(V\), context
    size \(C\), and embedding size \(N\)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a (relatively) less simple method than my original (relatively) simple answer, which is a bit more flexible and ever so slightly better tested. It requires `etoolbox` and `xparse`. (You could easily dispense with the latter, if desired, but it is convenient.)

- As I've set things up, this modifies all `tikzpicture` environments.

  - It could be broadened to include `\tikz` macros, if required.
  - If the global impact is undesirable, remove the `every picture` definition and simply use `mark out` in the optional argument to `tikzpicture`.
- It allows adjustment for material on the left, right, both or neither.

The only requirement for the simple case based on the MWE is to insert `\tikzmarkerwest` at the point in the picture where you want to mark the left of the part of the picture which `\caption` should use to place the caption. If you don't use the macro at all in the picture, the code just falls back to the left of the picture's bounding box, when the picture is complete. This happens in the second `subfigure` in the example.

The code of the first `subfigure` is rearranged, so that everything which `\caption` should ignore comes after the first part of the picture. `\tikzmarkerwest` is then inserted to mark the left side at this point.

```
...
      \foreach \word in {the, cat, sat}{%
        \draw[->] (\word) -- (in_\word);
        \draw[->] (in_\word) -- (in);
      }
      \draw[->] (in) -- (out);
```

That's everything we want `\caption` to use for placement, so mark the left of the picture now.

```
      \tikzmarkerwest
```

Now we put the stuff to the left of that point, which `\caption` should ignore.

```
      \node[left=of the, outer sep=0] (embed) {embed};
      \node[above=2cm of embed, outer sep=0] (concatenate) {concatenate};
      \node[above=1cm of concatenate, outer sep=0] {softmax};
```

Now we finish the picture and add the caption and label as usual.

```
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{CBOW model}\label{fig:cbow}
```

[image: adjusted caption]

For material on the right, `\tikzmarkereast` can be used instead of, or as well as, `\tikzmarkerwest`.

In some cases, it is inconvenient or impossible to rearrange the code in a picture in this way. It just can't be drawn easily, if at all, in the order required. For this reason, `\tikzmarkereast` and `\tikzmarkerwest` support an optional argument. If specified, this should be a coordinate in round brackets, as usual for coordinates. In this case everything to the right or left of the specified coordinate will be ignored when placing the caption.

The code which supports this defines the macro `\tikzmarkerwest` as follows.

```
\NewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkerwest { D () {current bounding box.west} } {%
  \coordinate (tikz marker west) at (#1);
  \let\tikzmarkerwestdefault\relax
}
```

This creates a coordinate `(tikz marker west)` in the appropriate place. It then makes sure that `\tikzmarkerwestdefault` does nothing successfully.

`\tikzmarkereast` is defined in the same way.

```
\NewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkereast { D () {current bounding box.east} } {%
  \coordinate (tikz marker east) at (#1);
  \let\tikzmarkereastdefault\relax
}
```

We make sure `\tikzmarkerwestdefault` and `\tikzmarkereast` are defined. By default, they do nothing.

```
\NewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkerwestdefault {} {}
\NewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkereastdefault {} {}
```

Now for the Ti*k*Z code.

```
\tikzset{%
```

The style `mark out` adds code to be executed at the beginning and end of the current picture, if given in the optional argument to the environment, or of all pictures, if configured as below.

```
  mark out/.style={%
    execute at begin picture={%
      \RenewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkerwestdefault {}
      {%
        \coordinate (tikz marker west) at (current bounding box.west);
      }%
      \RenewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkereastdefault {}
      {%
        \coordinate (tikz marker east) at (current bounding box.east);
      }%
    },
```

This redefines our `\tikzmarkerwestdefault` and `\tikzmarkereastdefault` macros to create coordinates `(tikz marker west)` and `(tikz marker east)` at the left and right of the current bounding box. These are just definitions, overriding the default empty ones. They don't actually create any coordinates yet.

```
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzmarkerwestdefault
      \tikzmarkereastdefault
```

At the end of the picture, we execute `\tikzmarkerwestdefault`. If `\tikzmarkerwest` has been called within the picture, this will do nothing successfully. Otherwise, it will create the marker at the left of the current bounding box, which is the final bounding box for the picture. Similarly for `\tikzmarkereastdefault`.

```
      \path let \p1=(tikz marker west), \p2=(current bounding box.west), \n1={\x1-\x2} in \pgfextra{\xdef\myadjustwest{\n1}} ;
```

This calculates the difference between the `x` part of the `(tikz marker west)` coordinate and the `x` part of the coordinate at the left of the current bounding box. Typically, this will be 0pt. But, if `\tikzmarkerwest` has been called, the distance of the marker node from the left of the current bounding box may be non-zero. (Indeed, if the macro has been called, this will presumably be the case as that's the only reason to use the macro.)

Now we do the same for `(tikz marker east)` and the right of the current bounding box.

```
      \path let \p1=(tikz marker east), \p2=(current bounding box.east), \n1={\x2-\x1} in \pgfextra{\xdef\myadjusteast{\n1}} ;
    },
  },


  every picture/.style={mark out},
```

This line applies the `mark out` style to all Ti*k*Z pictures. If this causes problems, remove it and add `mark out` to the pictures you want it for.

```
}
\newlength\myadjustwest
\newlength\myadjusteast
```

Make sure `\myadjustwest` and `\myadjusteast` are available regardless.

```
\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{%
  \captionsetup{margin={\myadjustwest,\myadjusteast}}%
}{\typeout{OK!}}{\typeout{Oh, no!}}
```

This adapts the end of all `tikzpicture` environments to modify the `\caption` correctly. You should substitute meaningful messages for yourself in place of `OK!` and `Oh, no!`, if you use this.

The following example set illustrates the basic possibilities. If you want to place the caption relative to, say, a shaded rectangle, you can't (at all easily) shade part of it, then another part and then another part, marking the bounding box in between stages appropriately. Therefore, for this case, we use the optional arguments for `\tikzmarkerwest` and/or `\tikzmarkereast`, to get positions for captions focusing on the red end of the visible light spectrum, the blue end and an in-between bit left-of-centre.

For the reds ...

```
...
      \shade [shading=wave, shading angle=90] (0,0) rectangle ++(\linewidth,1) coordinate [pos=.4] (r);
      \tikzmarkereast(r)
...
```

For the blues ...

```
...
      \shade [shading=wave, shading angle=90] (0,0) rectangle ++(\linewidth,1) coordinate [pos=.6] (b);
      \tikzmarkerwest(b)
...
```

For the innards ...

```
...
      \shade [shading=wave, shading angle=90] (0,0) rectangle ++(\linewidth,1) coordinate [pos=.1] (a) coordinate [pos=.5] (b);
      \tikzmarkereast(b)
      \tikzmarkerwest(a)
...
```

[image: adjusted captions for visible light spectrum]

Complete code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\pdfminorversion=7
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377652/ addaswyd o gwestiwn d125q: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/377476/
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage[list]{subcaption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,tikz,etoolbox,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, fit, positioning, calc}
\usepackage[active, tightpage, floats, displaymath]{preview}
\mathtoolsset{%
  mathic=true
}
\NewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkerwest { D () {current bounding box.west} } {%
  \coordinate (tikz marker west) at (#1);
  \let\tikzmarkerwestdefault\relax
}
\NewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkerwestdefault {} {}
\NewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkereast { D () {current bounding box.east} } {%
  \coordinate (tikz marker east) at (#1);
  \let\tikzmarkereastdefault\relax
}
\NewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkereastdefault {} {}
\tikzset{%
  mark out/.style={%
    execute at begin picture={%
      \RenewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkerwestdefault {}
      {%
        \coordinate (tikz marker west) at (current bounding box.west);
      }%
      \RenewDocumentCommand \tikzmarkereastdefault {}
      {%
        \coordinate (tikz marker east) at (current bounding box.east);
      }%
    },
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzmarkerwestdefault
      \tikzmarkereastdefault
      \path let \p1=(tikz marker west), \p2=(current bounding box.west), \n1={\x1-\x2} in \pgfextra{\xdef\myadjustwest{\n1}} ;
      \path let \p1=(tikz marker east), \p2=(current bounding box.east), \n1={\x2-\x1} in \pgfextra{\xdef\myadjusteast{\n1}} ;
    },
  },
  every picture/.style={mark out},
}
\newlength\myadjustwest
\newlength\myadjusteast
\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{%
  \captionsetup{margin={\myadjustwest,\myadjusteast}}%
}{\typeout{OK!}}{\typeout{Oh, no!}}

% for the examples
\definecolor{wave start}{wave}{380}
\definecolor{wave violet}{wave}{400}
\definecolor{wave indigo}{wave}{445}
\definecolor{wave blue}{wave}{475}
\definecolor{wave green}{wave}{510}
\definecolor{wave yellow}{wave}{570}
\definecolor{wave orange}{wave}{590}
\definecolor{wave red}{wave}{650}
\definecolor{wave end}{wave}{780}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{wave}{100bp}{% manual 1088; xcolor manual; does not work to use wave model directly (?); https://science-edu.larc.nasa.gov/EDDOCS/Wavelengths_for_Colors.html
  color(0bp)=(wave start);
  color(25bp)=(wave start);
  color(27bp)=(wave violet);% 400 nm
  color(33bp)=(wave indigo);% 445nm
  color(37bp)=(wave blue);% 475nm
  color(41bp)=(wave green);% 510nm
  color(49bp)=(wave yellow);% 570nm
  color(51bp)=(wave orange);% 590nm
  color(59bp)=(wave red);% 650nm
  color(75bp)=(wave end);% 780nm
  color(100bp)=(wave end)
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.60\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
      \node[draw, label=below:the] (the) {\(\mathbf{W}\)};
      \node[draw, right=of the, label=below:cat] (cat) {\(\mathbf{W}\)};
      \node[draw, right=of cat, label=below:sat] (sat) {\(\mathbf{W}\)};
      \node[draw, fit=(the.west) (the.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of the] (in_the) {};
      \node[draw, fit=(cat.west) (cat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of cat] (in_cat) {};
      \node[draw, fit=(sat.west) (sat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of sat] (in_sat) {};
      \node[draw, fit={($(cat.west) + (-8pt,0pt)$) ($(cat.east) + (8pt,0pt)$)}, pattern=vertical lines, above=2cm of cat] (in) {};
      \node[draw, above=of in, label=above:mat] (out) {\(\mathbf{b}\), \(\mathbf{U}\)};
      \foreach \word in {the, cat, sat}{%
        \draw[->] (\word) -- (in_\word);
        \draw[->] (in_\word) -- (in);
      }
      \draw[->] (in) -- (out);
      \tikzmarkerwest
      \node[left=of the, outer sep=0] (embed) {embed};
      \node[above=2cm of embed, outer sep=0] (concatenate) {concatenate};
      \node[above=1cm of concatenate, outer sep=0] {softmax};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{CBOW model}\label{fig:cbow}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
      \node[draw, label=below:cat] (cat) {\(\mathbf{W}\)};
      \node[draw, fit=(cat.west) (cat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of cat] (in) {};
      \node[draw, above=2cmof in, label=above:on] (on) {\(\mathbf{b}\), \(\mathbf{U}\)};
      \node[draw, left=of on, label=above:sat] (sat) {\(\mathbf{b}\), \(\mathbf{U}\)};
      \node[draw, right=of on, label=above:the] (the) {\(\mathbf{b}\), \(\mathbf{U}\)};
      \draw[->] (cat) -- (in);
      \foreach \word in {sat, on, the}{%
        \draw[->] (in) -- (\word);
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Skip\=/gram model}\label{fig:sg}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{\protect\Verb+Word2Vec+ with vocabulary size \(V\), context size \(C\), and embedding size \(N\)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.33\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \shade [shading=wave, shading angle=90] (0,0) rectangle ++(\linewidth,1) coordinate [pos=.4] (r);
      \tikzmarkereast(r)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Reds.}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{.33\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \shade [shading=wave, shading angle=90] (0,0) rectangle ++(\linewidth,1) coordinate [pos=.6] (b);
      \tikzmarkerwest(b)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Blues.}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{.33\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \shade [shading=wave, shading angle=90] (0,0) rectangle ++(\linewidth,1) coordinate [pos=.1] (a) coordinate [pos=.5] (b);
      \tikzmarkereast(b)
      \tikzmarkerwest(a)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Innards.}
  \end{subfigure}\par
  \caption{Main figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I did not edit my first answer, because it might be useful for some people as it is.

This new answer calculates the margins for the caption. For this there are some macros in the preamble. And then three commands have to be placed. They are all without any arguments.

In the picture the main part (i.e. the part under which the caption should be centered) must be drawn first. Then `\pgfremembermainx` has to be inserted. It set coordinates to remember the outermost x-positions so far. After that the parts overlapping the main part to the left and the right have to be drawn.

Right at the end, just before `\end{tikzpicture}`, the command `\pgfgetoverlap` must be placed. It calculates the overlap (relative to the main part) to both sides and stores them in the dimen registers `\overlapleft` and `\overlapright`. Both are set global, so they can be used after the `tikzpicture`. Note: everything drawn after `\pgfgetoverlap` would not be taken into account for calculating the overlap.

And finally between the `tikzpicture` and the caption the margins are set with `\captionsetmargins`. Its effect is local since it's in the `subfigure` environment. It should not be used outside the environment, because it would set the margins for all captions since the optional argument (`[subfigure]`) can't be used here. Of course this only works after the picture, because the overlaps are not known before it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage[list]{subcaption}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, fit, positioning, calc, shapes.arrows}

\usepackage[active, tightpage, floats, displaymath]{preview}

\mathtoolsset{%
  mathic=true
}

% Vectors and matrices
\renewcommand*{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\trans}{\intercal}

% Operators
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------
% code for automatic setting of caption margins
\makeatletter
\newdimen\overlapleft
\newdimen\overlapright

\newcommand{\pgfremembermainx}{%
    \coordinate (main west) at (current bounding box.west);
    \coordinate (main east) at (current bounding box.east);
}
\newcommand{\pgfgetoverlap}{%
    \pgfextractx{\@tempdima}{%
        \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{west}}%
                     {\pgfpointanchor{main west}{center}}%
    }%
    \global\overlapleft=\@tempdima
    \pgfextractx{\@tempdima}{%
        \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{main east}{center}}%
                     {\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{east}}%
    }%
    \global\overlapright=\@tempdima
}
\newcommand{\captionsetmargins}{%
    % no additional calculation required here
    \captionsetup{margin={\overlapleft,\overlapright}}%
}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
% not needed here
%  \captionsetup[subfigure]{margin={2.5cm, 0cm}}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.60\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
      \node[draw, rectangle, label=below:the] (the) {\(\mat W\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, right=of the, label=below:cat] (cat) {\(\mat W\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, right=of cat, label=below:sat] (sat) {\(\mat W\)};

      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(the.west) (the.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of the] (in_the) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(cat.west) (cat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of cat] (in_cat) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(sat.west) (sat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of sat] (in_sat) {};

      \node[draw, rectangle, fit={($(cat.west) + (-8pt,0pt)$) ($(cat.east) + (8pt,0pt)$)}, pattern=vertical lines, above=2cm of cat] (in) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, above=of in, label=above:mat] (out) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};

      % remember the x-coordinates of the main part      
      \pgfremembermainx
      % \useasboundingbox was here in the first answer

      % not taken into account for the picture size
      \node[left=of the, outer sep=0] (embed) {embed};
      \node[above=2cm of embed, outer sep=0] (concatenate) {concatenate};
      \node[above=1cm of concatenate, outer sep=0] {softmax};

      % this belongs to the main part, but it doesn't increase its size
      % otherwise it must be moved before \pgfremembermainx
      \foreach \word in {the, cat, sat}{%
        \draw[->] (\word) -- (in_\word);
        \draw[->] (in_\word) -- (in);
      }

      \draw[->] (in) -- (out);

      %for testing, if it also works with overlap to the right
      %\node[draw, right= of sat] {t};

      % must be right before \end{tikzpicture}, everything after it
      % would not be taken into account for the calculation of the overlap
      \pgfgetoverlap
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % setting the caption margins
    % moving this here sets the margin locally (only for the current environment)
    % and here the computed values for the margins are known
    \captionsetmargins
    \caption{CBOW model}\label{fig:cbow}
  \end{subfigure}
% no longer needed
%  \captionsetup[subfigure]{margin={0cm,0cm}}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
      \node[draw, rectangle, label=below:cat] (cat) {\(\mat W\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, fit=(cat.west) (cat.east), pattern=vertical lines, above=of cat] (in) {};
      \node[draw, rectangle, above=2cmof in, label=above:on] (on) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, left=of on, label=above:sat] (sat) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};
      \node[draw, rectangle, right=of on, label=above:the] (the) {\(\vec b\), \(\mat U\)};

      \draw[->] (cat) -- (in);
      \foreach \word in {sat, on, the}{%
        \draw[->] (in) -- (\word);
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Skip\=/gram model}\label{fig:sg}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{\protect\Verb+Word2Vec+ with vocabulary size \(V\), context
    size \(C\), and embedding size \(N\)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```